# Javascript: getting data-attr on click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i am trying to alert `data-attr` value on click event like this

```
<div class="col-md-2 col-xs-2" onclick="changeImage(event)">
    <img src="img/img1.jpg" data-attr="img1.jpg">
    <img src="img/img2.jpg"  data-attr="img2.jpg">
</div> 

<script type="text/javascript">
        function changeImage(event){
                    var target= event.target;                    
                    alert(target.data-attr);
        }
</script>
```

here if i target  src of image that will alert but `data-attr` wont how can i  do  this pleas help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the `dataset` property to retrieve `data-*` attributes:

```
function changeImage(event) {
    var target = event.target;
    alert(target.dataset.attr);
}
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/k65drhfu/)

Also, seeing as you tagged this question with jQuery, here's a jQuery implementation without the ugly `onclick` attribute:

```
<div class="col-md-2 col-xs-2">
    <img src="img/img1.jpg" data-attr="img1.jpg">
    <img src="img/img2.jpg" data-attr="img2.jpg">
</div>
```

```js
$(function() {
    $('div.col-md-2').on('click', 'img', function() {
        alert($(this).data('attr'))
    });
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/k65drhfu/2/)

Comment: and to assign that attribute as src to an image i am using this  is that  okay  document.getElementById("mainimg").src='images/'.target.getAttribute('data-attr')

Comment: No, don't use `getAttribute` for reading `data` attributes as it makes another pointless request to the DOM. Use `dataset.attr`, as I mentioned in my answer. Also `+` is the concatenation character in JS. Use this: `document.getElementById("mainimg").src = 'images/' + target.dataset.attr;`, or jQuery: `$('#mainimg').prop('src', $(this).data('attr'));`

Answer (score 1):

Use `getAttribute()`

```
function changeImage(event){
      var target= event.target;                    
      console.log( target.getAttribute('data-attr') );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `ELEMENT.getAttribute("ATTRIBUTE")` to get any Attribute on a Element:

And in case of the `data-` Attribute you can also use `ELEMENT.dataset.ATTRIBUTE`:

```html
<div class="col-md-2 col-xs-2" onclick="changeImage(event)">
  <img src="img/img1.jpg" data-attr="img1.jpg">
  <img src="img/img2.jpg" data-attr="img2.jpg">
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function changeImage(event) {
    var target = event.target;
    alert(target.getAttribute("data-attr"));
    alert(target.dataset.attr);
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `getAttribute()` function. Following code depicst the same

```js
function changeImage(event) {
  var target = event.target;
  console.log(target.getAttribute("data-attr"));
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-2 col-xs-2" onclick="changeImage(event)">
  <img src="img/img1.jpg" data-attr="img1.jpg">
  <img src="img/img2.jpg" data-attr="img2.jpg">
</div>
```